# AWS Lambda: how to give ffmpeg large files?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, aws-lambda, amazon-efs

*[Please note that this is now an old question, and that AWS has updated size limits. I would close it if there were an option of "no longer as relevant as when first posted".]*

Scenario:

Using AWS Lambda (Node.js), I want to process large files from S3 ( > 1GB).
The /tmp fs limit of 512MB means that I can't copy the S3 input there.
I can certainly increase the Lambda memory space, in order to read in the files.

- Do I pass the memory buffer to ffmpeg? (node.js, how?)
- Or....should I just make an EFS mount point and use that as the transcoding scratchpad?

Comment: You realize that Lambdas has a time limit of 15 minutes? Transcoding a video will probably take longer than that, unless you are just remuxing or transcoding audio.

Comment: ffmpeg can use http/https URLs as input, so for at least the input side of the problem, you can use presigned links.  ffmpeg can also output to stdout, but for many containers this is problematic.  You're going to have a world of pain, unless you use something like ECS or EFS.

Comment: concatenating and getting short clips - I misspoke when I said transcoding.  re: pipe.. so, passing a huge buffer to child_process.spawnSync() as input?  The more I think about it, the more EFS seems like the sane path.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is to make sure you clean up your EFS shares afterwards, because I don't think it is considered transient storage.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the HTTP(s) protocol as input for ffmpeg.

Lambda has max 10GB memory limit, and data transfer speed from S3 is around 300MB per second the last time I test. So if you have only 1GB max video and are not doing memory intensive transformation, this approach should work fine

```
ffmpeg -i "https://public-qk.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/sample.mp4" -ss 00:00:10 -vframes 1 -f image2 "image%03d.jpg"
```

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg works on files, so maybe an alternative would be to setup a unix pipe and then read that pipe with ffmpeg, constantly feeding it with the s3 stream.

But maybe you'd wanna consider running this as an ECS task instead, you wouldn't have a time constraint, and not the same storage constraint either. Cold start of it using Fargate would be 1-2 minutes though, which maybe isn't acceptable?

Comment: I would want to avoid cold start.  too bad that lambda does not provide a config option for /tmp fs size.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda now supports up to 10Gb storage:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-now-supports-up-to-10-gb-ephemeral-storage/

[image: Lambda no supports up to 10Gb storage]

Update with cli:
`$ aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name PDFGenerator --ephemeral-storage '{"Size": 10240}'`

Comment: yep, if only that were true a year ago :)  Much easier now.